# Unable to load MVC partial view under angular 6 component templateurl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-cli, angular6, webpack-2

Created the Angular 6 project with Asp .net MVC 5, but unable able to load the component templateurl through MVC Controllor action url. I am Getting "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ...." Have uploaded the sample project here
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArXFVBz69evCgXZqaNWfqvuNi3fx

It would be great if any one can help.

Comment: I checked your project and there is nothing in your routing file. What you want to do exactly?

Comment: my app.component.ts's templateURL should come from MVC partial View, i.e: ~/Home/AppComponent

Comment: you can include your partial view using ng-include in the app.component.html file. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: ngInclude is not available angular 6

Comment: i need to use something like this `@Component({
    templateUrl: '/Template/Index'
})
export class TemplateComponent {}` And this was possible with SystmeJS before upgrating to angular cli (webpack)